# How to pass multiple host header from postman

Tags: post, postman, hostheaders

I am trying to add  multiple host header for post http request on postman , but I am getting error like **Error: hostHeader.startsWith is not a function** .
If I pass  single header it is working , but if I pass one more header it is throwing the error could not send the request with the above message.
Is there any configuration I need to have to allow multiple host headers

Comment: please show what you did, by code and image.

Comment: I have the same problem. I need to send duplicate Host headers to check my services. This will fail in Postman: curl --location --request GET 'http://localhost:8765/my-service/service \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--header 'Host: x' \
--header 'Host: y'